Add Custom Fields and Actions to Elementor Collected Submissions
Elementor Pro has the option to collect form submissions.
That's a great feature.
However, I would like to take it further and create a sequence (or an action) after clicking the Update button.
For example, I want to add two checkboxes: one will be 'We received your ticket and are working on it,' and the second will be 'We received your ticket, but we're sorry, we can't proceed with it.'
Once I select the box and click Update, I want the answer sent to the submitter's email.
Can it be done? How can I do it?
